# Sublime Text 2 - AutoFileName

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is it possible to configure the AutoFileName plugin for Sublime Text 2 to recognize TypeScript reference path attributes and allow auto-completion for other .ts files in my project?

For example, if I had a file structure like:

```
scripts
  models
    MyModel.ts
  services
    MyService.ts
```

Then in `MyService.ts`, I would want the path attribute in the reference tag to allow auto-completion of `../models/MyModel.ts`

```
/// <reference path="../models/MyModel.ts" />
```

I was hoping to be able to do this using the "auto_complete_triggers" setting in my user/preferences.sublime-settings file, but really have no idea how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

#### This is a syntax (tmLanguage) issue

[AutoFileName](https://github.com/BoundInCode/AutoFileName) must recognize a string pattern inside the comment line for it to work.

I use [ArcticTypescript](https://github.com/Phaiax/ArcticTypescript) and have just made a [pull request](https://github.com/Phaiax/ArcticTypescript/pull/19) to fix this tmLanguage issue. Edit: It is merged now.

[image]

If you use another package for syntax highlighting like [better-typescript](https://github.com/lavrton/sublime-better-typescript) please open an issue to correct the syntax definition.

Answer (score 0):

Open **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> AutoFileName -> Settings-Default`** and copy the entire contents to a new file (you can set the syntax to JSON if you prefer), then close the Default file (you never want to make changes to the default settings for any plugin, always use the User settings in case you mess something up and need to revert). Modify the `"afn_valid_scopes"` setting to include `"ts"`, and you should be all set. Save the file as `Packages/User/autofilename.sublime-settings` where `Packages` is the folder opened when selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**.

If you used the following setting in your Sublime user preferences:

```js
"auto_complete_triggers":
    [
      {
         "characters": "/",
         "selector": "string.quoted.double.html,string.quoted.single.html, source.css"
      }
    ]
```

then add a comma `,` after `source.css` then add `string source.ts` and save.

Comment: doesn't seem to work. I keep getting ('completion json error : ', u'null\n') in console